# Idiomatic syntax for Option when the meaningful value is None

Tags: scala, coding-style

This is purely a coding-style question.

A function I'm calling returns an `Option`, and I want to take a specific action if it's equal to `None`.

Say, for example, that I'm trying to create a default user at boot time if it doesn't already exist. I'd call a function that attempts to find a user that matches the default one, and returns an `Option[User]`.

If that return value is `None`, I'd like to run some user creation code. If not, I'm done.

I'm wondering what's the most idiomatic Scala syntax for this. What I have so far is:

```
def getUser(name: String): Option[User] = ...

getUser("admin") getOrElse createUser("admin", "ChangeThisNow!")

getUser("admin") match {
    case None => createUser("admin", "ChangeThisNow!")
    case _    =>
}

if(getUser("admin") == None) createUser("admin", "ChangeThisNow!")
```

The first solution seems like the most functional one, but I can't help but feel that there might be better ones - possibly by using partially applied functions, which I admit I'm still a bit fuzzy about.

Comment: Definitely `getOrElse`. You can actually do something with the resulting user, too.

Comment: I'd use `getOrElse`. If you have to go with the conditional for some reason, use `.isEmpty` instead of `== None`.

Comment: I usually take these questions to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JasonG didn't realize this existed. You're right, of course, and I'll do that from here on out. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Nobody mentioned `getUser(name) orElse createUser(name)` with create returning Option; but of course what everyone is secretly thinking is: `getUser(name).fold(createUser(name))(identity)`.

Comment: @JasonG I noticed one of your four CR questions was booted! Those guys are so exclusive. I think I'd wait for SE to offer a tool to pick the best site for a given post before I started playing games. It's one thing if there's a real guru at the top of the mountain you have to climb. Anyway, didn't Odersky's Scala with Style talk ultimately imply that all Scala questions are questions of style?

Comment: @som-snytt - haven't heard that one - I'll put it on the lunchtime watch list. :) Been watching more haskell related stuff lately. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since in your case the goal is to cause a side effect, I'd use a conditional to stress that, instead of using `getOrElse`.

```
if (getUser("admin").isEmpty) 
  createUser("admin", "ChangeThisNow!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that scala is a multi-paradigm language.
In addition to syntax, you want to consider concepts such as cohesion (single responsibility) and so you can consider the composition of your objects in addition to the actual idioms you use in the syntax.

The OO way might be to decorate the object/class that getUser belongs to in to put that concern of creating the user in a wrapper so that other code that calls the getUser function never has to deal with that concern. This fits nicely with open/closed principle and single responsibility. This is a bit of an anemic domain model anti-pattern here but may show how OO can be used to extend the conversation into actual design.

Either pattern matching or getOrElse are reasonable solutions. Generally if statements aren't used against Monads like the option - at least not that I see.

Either way, I beleive the expression should return the result even if there are side effects (user creation).

```
case class User(name: String)    

class UserService {
  def getUser(name: String): Option[User] = ???
  def createUser(name: String): User = ???
}

class UserServiceDecorator extends UserService {
  override def getUser(name: String): Option[User] =  
    Some(super.getUser(name).getOrElse(super.createUser(name)))
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because it's a good answer - just not to the right question. In this particular case, I don't need nor want a return value, the purpose is just to make sure, at boot time, that the admin account exists and to create a default one if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Really the best way to do this is to assign the result to a meaningful variable name so your future code doesn't need to know if `createUser` was called or not.

`val user = getUser("admin").getOrElse(createUser("admin", "ChangeThisNow!"))`

This way you can use the `user` variable regardless of if you've created a new user or not.

Comment: I didn't make this obvious in my question, but in this specific case, I couldn't care less about the resulting value - I just want to create the user if he doesn't exist, but I don't have anything else to do with it afterwards.